# Django NOT IN without NOT NULL

Tags: django, django-orm

I am implementing "ignored users" functionality to my board software. That functionality has to hide threads started by members user ignores. I have decided to fetch ID's of ignored users to python list and if that list is not empty, add exclude to query set.

```
if ignored_users:
    queryset_threads = queryset_threads.exclude(start_poster_id__in=ignored_users)
```

However, there is problem with how exclude works, which is "call filter() and add NOT at the beginning". Here, filter produces following SQL:

```
`threads_thread` . `start_poster_id` IN (2, 3, 4, 5) AND `threads_thread` . `start_poster_id` NOT NULL
```

How do I get rid of that NOT NULL? Threads posted by members that have deleted their accounts have NULL in "start_poster_id" column.

Answer (score 0):

The raw SQL that you posted does not seem correct. It's actually invalid as written. What value is `NOT NULL`?

Regardless, the `NULL` is not added from `.exclude()`. It must be added from somewhere else in your code.

`.exclude()` simply adds `WHERE NOT` to the parameters you specify - it does not add it's own.

[See the docs for .exclude() here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exclude)

For example:

```
>>> query = Threads.objects.exclude(id__in=[1,2,3,4]).query.__str__()
>>> query
'SELECT `test_threads`.`id`, `test_threads`.`threads_name` 
FROM `test_threads` 
WHERE NOT (`test_threads`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4))'
```

Is your original assignment of `queryset_threads` filtering for `NOT NULL`? Similar to this:

```
>>> query = Threads.objects.filter(id__isnull=False)
>>> query = query.exclude(id__in=[1,2,3,4]).query.__str__()
>>> query
'SELECT `test_threads`.`id`, `test_threads`.`threads_name` 
FROM `test_threads` 
WHERE (`test_threads`.`id` IS NOT NULL 
AND NOT (`test_threads`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4)))'
```

Comment: NOT NULL origins from start_poster ForeignKey field that can be null (thats when thread belongs to deleted member). When I do filter(start_poster_id__in=[1, 2, 3, 4]), that results in "IN AND NOT NULL" SQL. when I use exclude, it simply wraps filter in NOT. What I am looking for is to tell Django to ignore fact that field can be null. Right now I am doing it using custom WHERE via .extra()

Comment: Please post the entire view. Neither filter nor exclude should be adding an extra parameter for the foreign key. The full view will help me see where `NULL` is being specified.